# Erro with getSingleResult()

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I'm trying to return the only result of a query as follows:

```
public UsuarioMenuVO consultar(UsuarioMenuVO usuarioMenuVO) throws MetrusDAOException {
    UsuarioMenuVO usuarioMenu = null;
    EntityManager em = null;

    StringBuilder jpql = new StringBuilder();
    jpql.append("SELECT um FROM ").append(UsuarioMenuVO.class.getName()).append(" um ");

    if(usuarioMenuVO.getId() != null){
        jpql.append(" WHERE 1 = 1 ");
        jpql.append(" AND um.id = :idUsuarioMenu ");
    } else if(usuarioMenuVO.getUsuarioVO().getId() != null){
        jpql.append(" WHERE um.usuarioVO.id = :idUsuario ");
    }

    try{
        em = getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<UsuarioMenuVO> q = em.createQuery(jpql.toString(), UsuarioMenuVO.class);

        if(usuarioMenuVO.getId() != null){
            q.setParameter("idUsuarioMenu", usuarioMenuVO.getId());
        } else if(usuarioMenuVO.getUsuarioVO().getId() != null){
            q.setParameter("idUsuario", usuarioMenuVO.getUsuarioVO().getId());
        }
        usuarioMenu = (UsuarioMenuVO)q.getSingleResult();
        return usuarioMenu;
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.error(e, e);
        throw new MetrusDAOException(e);
    }finally {
        closeEntityManager(em);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
[EL Fine]: 2020-10-16 09:55:34.255--ServerSession(1977519967)--Connection(1898684397)--Thread(Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads])--SELECT COD_USUARIO_MENU, STA_ADMINISTRA_USUARIO, COD_ATUALIZACAO, DAT_ATUALIZ, DAT_CRIACAO_USUARIO, DAT_ULT_ACESSO, DAT_VALIDADE, CRP_PASSWORD, COD_SETOR, SIT_USUARIO, STA_SUPER, SEQ_USUARIO FROM ME_USUARIOS_MENU WHERE ((? = ?) AND (COD_USUARIO_MENU = ?))
    bind => [1, 1, "ANILDO"]
16/out 09:55:34,262 ERROR (UsuarioMenuDAO.java:53) - javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
javax.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.throwNoResultException(QueryImpl.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
```

The query returns value when executed in Oracle. Thinking that the problem was with getSingleResult (), I put the result in a list and tried to get index 0 from the list but I also got an error. I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: I think there is no data in your db. That's why you getting this. Moreover, what do you want here?

Comment: @user404 but there is data, when I execute the same query assembled by the application in the database, the data is returned.

Comment: please check this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613113/javax-persistence-noresultexception-getsingleresult-did-not-retrieve-any-enti)

Comment: How did you inserted data into database? If you inserted from database client have you committed that transaction?